# Can we create database by code on aws server

Tags: php, mysql, amazon-web-services

In my project, it's required to set up database on run time. I found core PHP have MySQL query to perform this but it's run locally and not on the server.

Is there any possible way to achieve this either on AWS, vps or any other cloud server? Does this query run good and fit my requirement?

```
$conn =new mysqli('localhost', 'root', '');
$sql = "CREATE DATABASE $dbname";
if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {
    mysqli_select_db($conn,"$dbname");
}
```

Comment: Could you be more specific what you are trying to achieve? You can run this query on aws and other cloud provider, but it depends on your specific use case.

Comment: I am looking to create database when any user create account on website and that datbase will only use for that user

Comment: For AWS you could use [RDS](https://aws.amazon.com/rds/mysql/). Once properly setup, in your command you would use RDS provided endpoint instead of `localhost`.

Comment: When you say "create a database", are you referring to creating a database **server**? The command you have shown above is to create a logical database _within_ an existing database server. (Yeah, confusing terminology, eh!) It would be helpful if you could Edit your question and tell us more about the architecture you want to achieve (eg what the database will be used for, whether it should go on the same server as your code or separately, whether you want automated backups, etc).

Comment: Thank you friends its work well on google cloud